# Fill a dataframe by matching the values of a vector with colnames

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I need to fill a dataframe in R by matching the values of a vector with column names.
The column names do not match exactly the names of the vector.
Below is an example:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = 4));
colnames(df) = c("AA", "BB", "CC")
vec1 = c(1,2,3) ; names(vec1) = c("BB745","456AA",  "123CC3") ;
vec2 = c(4,5,6) ; names(vec2) = c("BB745","456AA",  "123CC3")
```

The first lines of `df` should be

```
2 1 3
5 4 6
```

What would be the simpliest way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, I suppose that you have many `vec`s that you want to set all together in one dataframe based part common parts in their names.

So for example, you have this three `vec`s:

```
vec1 <- setNames(c(1,2,3), c("BB745","456AA",  "123CC3"))
vec2 <- setNames(c(3,2,1), c("BB345","113AA",  "543CC6"))
vec3 <- setNames(c(2,1,3), c("BB567","AA111",  "345CC8"))
```

And you want to set them together based on the presence of the following strings:

```
nn <-  c("AA", "BB", "CC")
```

In that case, I suggest you to proceed as follow.

Set up your `vec` in one list:

```
l <- list(vec1,vec2,vec3)
```

Then use this one line:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

nn_clps <- paste(nn, collapse = "|")
map_dfr(l, ~setNames(., str_extract(names(.), nn_clps))) %>% select(all_of(nn))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      AA    BB    CC
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     2     1     3
#> 2     2     3     1
#> 3     1     2     3
```

What does it do?

- We apply a function to each vector with `map` from the `purrr` package
- In this way, we take one `vec` a time and extract from the names the strings in `nn`: so one of `AA`, `BB` or `CC`. To do this we use `str_extract` from the `stringr` package.
- Then we rename each vector with the strings we extracted. We do this with `setNames`
- At the end, all the strings are set together in one unique dataframe. This is performed by `map_dfr`, which act like `map` but define the output as one unique dataframe (`dfr` stands for bind rows to a dataframe).
- to set up the columns in the intended orders, there are many ways. One could be with `select` from the `dplyr` package. `all_of` just translates the strings in names understandable from `select`. Also `[nn]` instead of  `%>% select(all_of(nn))` would have worked fine. Like this:

```
map_dfr(l, ~setNames(., str_extract(names(.), nn_clps)))[nn]
```

---

Check out `?map` to understand what `.` and `~` do.
In short: `~` is needed to create an anonymous function and `.` is a placeholder of `x` in the anonymous function.

---

All the code together.
I slightly modified it to set up the column in the order you intended.

```
vec1 <- setNames(c(1,2,3), c("BB745","456AA","123CC3"))
vec2 <- setNames(c(3,2,1), c("BB345","113AA","543CC6"))
vec3 <- setNames(c(2,1,3), c("BB567","AA111","345CC8"))
nn <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")
l <- list(vec1,vec2,vec3)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
nn_clps <- paste(nn, collapse = "|")
map_dfr(l, ~setNames(., str_extract(names(.), nn_clps))) %>% select(all_of(nn))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You've understood my problem! When I run your code, I've got an error `Argument 1 must have names` with the `map_dfr`function.

Comment: Can you please take the last part of my answer "all the code together" and run it? Tell me if you still have that error. Because I don't.

Comment: Yes I still have the error. I tried your code on 2 different R. Maybe your code uses a variable stored in your environment?

Comment: Can you please update your packages? Please update `purrr`, `dplyr`, `tibble`.

Comment: my version of the packages: `stringr_1.4.0`, `purrr_0.3.4`, `dplyr_1.0.2`, `tibble_3.0.3`

Comment: run `sessionInfo()` to see your versions. `update.packages()` to update your packages.

Comment: Perfect, it's now working :-) Thanks a lot for all your kindness

Comment: Last question: is it possible in the columns of the final dataframe to respect the order of the vector `nn` which is here `("AA", "BB", "CC")` but which could be `("CC", "BB", "AA")` ?

Comment: yes. Check out the code at the end. I slightly edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach using `tidyverse` functions. You can adapt the vector in a dataframe and then clean up the values to make a match using `left_join()`. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% mutate(Ref=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Ref) %>%
  left_join(
    vec1 %>% data.frame() %>% set_names(.,'Val') %>% rownames_to_column('name') %>%
      mutate(name=gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", name))
  ) %>%
  mutate(value=Val) %>% select(-Val) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  select(-Ref)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     AA    BB    CC
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     1     3
2     2     1     3
3     2     1     3
4     2     1     3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a base R approach, something like this could work:

```
vec1 <- c(1,2,3) ; names(vec1) <- c("BB745","456AA", "123CC3") 
vec2 <- c(3,4,5) ; names(vec2) <- c("BB845","545AA", "456CC3") 

my_fun <- function(vec) {
  headers <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")
  new_vals <- sapply(headers, 
                function(x) {
                  idx <- grepl(x, names(vec))
                  vec[idx]
                })
  names(new_vals) <- headers
  new_vals
}
row_list <- lapply(list(vec1, vec2), my_fun)
data.frame(do.call(rbind, row_list))
```

Output:

```
  AA BB CC
1  2  1  3
2  4  3  5
```